# Regex - extract indefinite number of hits

Tags: java, regex

The method getPolygonPoints() (see below) becomes a String name as parameter, which looks something like this:

```
points={{-100,100},{-120,60},{-80,60},{-100,100},{-100,100}}
```

The first number stands for the x-coordinate, the second for the y coordinate. For example,the first point is

```
x=-100
y=100
```

The second point is

```
x=-120
y=60
```

and so on.

Now I want to extract the points of the String and put them in a ArrayList, which has to look like this at the end:

```
[-100, 100, -120, 60, -80, 60, -100, 100, -100, 100]
```

The special feature here is, that the number of points in the given String changes and is not always the same.

I have written the following code:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getPolygonPoints(String name) {
    // the regular expression
    String regGroup = "[-]?[\\d]{1,3}";
    // compile the regular expression into a pattern
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{(" + regGroup + ")");
    // the mather
    Matcher matcher;

    ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // matcher that will match the given input against the pattern
    matcher = regex.matcher(name);
    int i = 1;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(i)));
        i++;
    }
    return points;
}
```

The first x coordinate is extracted correctly, but then a IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown. I think that happens, because group 2 is not defined.
I think at first I have to count the points and then iterate over this number. Inside of the iteration I would put the int values in the ArrayList with a simple add(). But I don't know how to do this. Maybe I don't understand the regex part at this point. Especially how the groups work.

Please help!

Comment: There is only 1 group in your regex which is the part enclosed in () so you cannot access group 2 or 3 as it is not there. just replace matcher.group(i) with matcher.group(1) in your matching loop

Comment: Why not you do SPLIT and REPLACE ?

Answer (score 4):

The part you don't seem to understand about the regex API is that the capture group number "reset" with every call to `find()`. Or, to put it another way: the number of the capture group is its position in the *pattern*, not in the *input string*.

You're also going about this the wrong way. You should match the whole construct you're looking for, in this case the `{x,y}` pairs. I'm assuming you don't want to validate the format of the whole string, so we can ignore the outside brackets and comma:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);

while (m.find()) {
    String x = m.group(1);
    String y = m.group(2);
    // parse and add to list
}
```

Alternately, since you don't care about which coordinate is X and which is Y, you can even do:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(name);
while (m.find()) {
    String xOrY = m.group();
    // parse etc.
}
```

Now, if you want to validate the input as well, I'd say that's a separate concern, I wouldn't necessarily try to do it in the same step as the parsing to keep the regex readable. (It might be possible in this case but if you don't need it why bother in the first place.)

Answer (score 4):

```
String points = "{{-100,100},{-120,60},{-80,60},{-100,100},{-100,100}}";

String[] strs = points.replaceAll("(\\{|\\})", "").split(",");

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(strs.length);

for (String s : strs)
{
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
```

Comment: +1 This is what i wish to prefer and need an acknowledgment from OP if it is possible to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it in just one line:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(name.replaceAll("(^\\w+=\\{+)|(\\}+$)", "").split("\\{?,\\}?"));
```

Your whole method would then be:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getPolygonPoints(String name) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(name.replaceAll("(^\\w+=\\{+)|(\\}+$)", "").split("\\{?,\\}?")));
}
```

This works by first stripping off the leading and trailing text, then splits on commas optionally surrounded by braces.

BTW You really should return the abstract type `List`, not the concrete implementation `ArrayList`.

Comment: @millimoose I misread the Q. I've fixed the leading "points=" part. And I'm now returning an ArrayList. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this regex:

```
((-?\d+)\s*,\s*(-?\d+))
```

It will give you three groups:

```
Group 1 : x
Group 2 : y
Group 3 : x,y
```

You can use which one is required to you.

Comment: I'd recommend using named groups in this case. REs are complicated enough without having to remember how nested capture groups are numbered.